# How to exclude a single-character expression from and to it from a slash-based partition?

Tags: java, regex, split

I would like to split some string in Java by forward slash symbol, but excude case when string contains only one symbol before and after it. Example - **xx/xx/xxyy/ZZZ** - splits ok, **x/x** - avoid splitting

I've tried to use a character set, but don't understand how to make an exclusion from standard **[/]**

I would be grateful for possible exclusion options

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunately, I am limited only by the expression pattern, since it is transferred to the external API.

Comment: Do you want to split `x/xxx`? I have an impression it should not be split.

Comment: No, only x/x case

Comment: Try either 1) `(?<!^[^/])/(?![^/]$)` or 2) `/(?!(?<=^[^/]/)[^/]$)`. You can't use lookarounds (zero-width assertions) inside character classes, you won't be able to use these inside square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex, which will not match a `/` if it is surrounded by only one character.

```
(?<=[^/\n].)/|/(?=.[^/\n])
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vVL4P0/1)**

Java code showing split,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("xx/xx/xxyy/ZZZ","x/x","/x/x/x/xxx");

list.forEach(x -> {
    String[] data = x.split("(?<=[^/\\n].)/|/(?=.[^/\\n])");
    System.out.println(x + " --> " + Arrays.toString(data));
});
```

Prints,

```
xx/xx/xxyy/ZZZ --> [xx, xx, xxyy, ZZZ]
x/x --> [x/x]
/x/x/x/xxx --> [/x/x/x, xxx]
```

Also, just in case you don't want to select a `/` for split, if it is surrounded by only one character on either side, you can use this regex,

```
(?<=[^/\n].)/(?=.[^/\n])
```

**[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/vVL4P0/2/)**

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer. And the final step - is it possible to transform it into character set and use in pair with others? For example, add to [ -]|[xXхХ]

Comment: @skydancer1990 No, you can't. Zero-width assertions cannot be used in character classes.

Comment: Does this mean that my problem cannot be solved through a character classes?

Comment: @skydancer1990 Exactly, as you need  lookarounds

Comment: Thank you very much again, I’ll continue search